# Linearize the cosine function

Tags: series-expansion, nonlinear

I want to linearize Cos, the cosine function, by Taylor expanson. I used a first order Taylor expanson and got `(1 - x²/2)`, but the function is not linear. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: `Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: If you want a nonzero linear term, then you have to expand around a point that's not an extremum. But I think your question has nothing to do with *Mathematica*. You couldn't have gotten the result you quote from a first-order expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You went to the 3rd order. The first order Taylor expansion for `Cos[x]` is always a linear function. The function depends on the point $x_0$ at which you do the expansion.

For the point $x_0=0$ you get:

```
Normal[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

> 1

on $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ you get

> π/2-x

Whatever point you choose, you get a linear function for it:

[image]

You can interactively try yourself:

```
Manipulate[
func=Normal@Series[Cos[x],{x,i,1}];
Show[Plot[Evaluate[{Cos[x],func}],{x,-2 π,2 π},PlotRange->{{-2 π,2 π},{-1.5,1.5}},PlotStyle->{Directive[Black],Directive[Opacity[0.5,Red]]}],Graphics[{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[{i,Cos[i]}],Inset[ToString[Chop[func],TraditionalForm],{-6,1.4},{Left,Top}]}]]
,{i,-2 π,2 π}]
```